# Test child transcended directive interaction with parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-test

I want to test an interaction between child and parent directive:
My example :

```
app.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>', 
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.add = function(x, y) {
        return x + y;
      }
  }
};
});

app.directive('bar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: '^foo',
    template: '<div></div>', 
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, foo) {

      console.log('link directive bar')
      scope.callFoo = function(x, y) {
        scope.sum = foo.add(x, y);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

I want to test an interaction between boo and test, I do not want to mock child directive (boo) here is my test:

```
it('ensures callFoo does whatever it is supposed to', function() {
  // Arrange
  var element = $compile('<div foo><bar></bar></div>')($scope);

  var ele = element.find('bar')
  var barScope = element.find('bar').scope();

  console.log('parent element :',element)
  console.log('child element :',ele)


  // Act Undefined :(
  barScope.callFoo(1, 2);

  // Assert
  expect(barScope.sum).toBe(3);
});
```

full example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/vYNFwpkbbHi4lsgwJkA9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directives are already compiled, and since you have `replace: true` on the `bar` directive you'd no longer find `bar` in the DOM. You can see this by looking at `element.html()`, which would show something like this in your case:

```
<div><div ng-transclude=""><div class="ng-scope"></div></div></div>
```

If you remove `replace: true` your test would work.

Otherwise, when jQuery is not loaded, jqLite is limited and its `find` method can only search tag names. So I tried to find your scope quickly like this:

```
var barScope = element.find("div").eq(2).scope()
```

Do you have jQuery loaded in your app? If so, you could load it in your test too, and then add some more info to the `bar` element like:

```
var element = $compile('<div foo><bar id="bar"></bar></div>')($scope);
```

Then you could find it like:

```
var barScope = element.find('#bar').scope();
```

Comment: Yes  var ele = angular.element(element.find('div')[2]) works for me :) Thanks Frank